# Is there a way to consume Kafka messages after high watermark?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am looking for a way to get messages later than High Watermark (HWM) from a Kafka topic partition. Is there a way to do it in the Java API?

I am fully aware that these messages are unconfirmed and can "disappear". However, I am interested in providing limited functionality when some replicas have disappeared for a topic partition and metadata quorum cannot be reached.

Is the truncation to HWM implemented on the client or server side? Would it be possible to get the messages using the wire protocol?